# How to show all the filters with woocommerce layered nav filter widget

Tags: widgets, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using on my woocommerce site the woocommerce layered nav widget that works perfectly. But actually I have set four filters by attributes and the relation between them is 'OR' that means that I can select more then one choice per attribute. But this means that it reduce the possibility of choices on other filters because, rightly, there are no products that satisfy all the conditions. Now my question is: 'Is it possible to print also not available choices in other attributes even if I can't click on them because they would show me no products?' Just to let the user knowing that there is at least 1 product with that attribute.

I try to do an example.

Filter 1 - Colors: orange, green, red, blue.

Filter 2 - Fruits: banana, apple, orange.

With default woocommerce layered nav widget functionalities if I select orange on colors, I won't see anymore 'apple' and 'banana' in second filter because there are no orange apples and bananas. What I would do is to display all the filters but turn them not selectable, because in our example, our greengrocer shop sell apples, bananas and orange but not blue bananas or blue apple.

Thanks in advance.